# Replace values of several columns with values mapping in other dataframe PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, left-join

I need to replace values of several columns (many more than those in the example, so I would like to avoid doing multiple left joins) of a dataframe with values from another dataframe (mapping).

Example:

`df1 EXAM`

| id | question1 | question2 | question3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 12 | 5 |
| 2 | 12 | 13 | 6 |
| 3 | 3 | 7 | 5 |

`df2 VOTE MAPPING` :

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | bad |
| 5 | insufficient |
| 6 | sufficient |
| 12 | very good |
| 13 | excellent |

`Output`

| id | question1 | question2 | question3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | very good | very good | insufficient |
| 2 | very good | excellent | sufficient |
| 3 | bad | *null* | insufficient |

Edit 1:  Corrected id for excellent in vote map

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can create a reference dataframe:

```
df3 = df2.select(
    func.create_map(func.col('id'), func.col('desc')).alias('ref')
).groupBy().agg(
    func.collect_list('ref').alias('ref')
).withColumn(
    'ref', func.udf(lambda lst: {k:v for element in lst for k, v in element.items()}, returnType=MapType(StringType(), StringType()))(func.col('ref'))
)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ref                                                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{3 -> bad, 12 -> good, 5 -> insufficient, 13 -> excellent, 6 -> sufficient}|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then you can replace the value in question columns by getting the value in reference with 1 `crossJoin`:

```
df4 = df1.crossJoin(df3)\
    .select(
        'id',
        *[func.col('ref').getItem(func.col(col)).alias(col) for col in df1.columns[1:]]
    )
df4.show(10, False)
+---+----+---------+------------+
|id |q1  |q2       |q3          |
+---+----+---------+------------+
|1  |good|good     |insufficient|
|2  |good|excellent|sufficient  |
|3  |bad |null     |insufficient|
+---+----+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi @Jresearcher, can my solution solve your question?